# How to render a data when state has been changed?

Tags: graphql, next.js

I am working on a data rendering in pagination using react and graphql.

When the component mounts, it fetches data I need

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.onCarRender()
}

onCarRender() {
    const { users, car } = this.props
    if(users) {
            this.setState({
               //car contains data I want to render on a screen
                carArray: car
            })
        }
    }
```

By graphql query, this.state.carArray contains 5 different data about cars and when I click another page, it fetches other 5 data about cars.

```
// carArray in Page 1

[
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
 { id: 2, driver: "Solid Snake", carName: "Prious" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 4, driver: "Zelda", carName: "Genesis" },
 { id: 5, driver: "Ryu", carName: "Range Rover" }
]

// carArray in Page 2

[
 { id: 6, driver: "Chun-Li", carName: "Lamborghini" },
 { id: 7, driver: "Blanca", carName: "Camry" },
 { id: 8, driver: "Yasuo", carName: "Benz E-Class" },
 { id: 9, driver: "Garen", carName: "Ferrari 911" },
 { id: 10, driver: "Teemo", carName: "M1 Abrams" }
]
```

But here is the problem :

When I click second page button, this.props.car does not fetch data I need until I refresh a browser.

Is this happening because I am using wrong life-cycle method in React.js?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using componentDidUpdate lifecycle method

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.car !== this.props.car) {
            this.onCarRender()
        }
    }
```